# Dynamically loading a JAR on a maven based project

Tags: java, maven, jar, swt

I am trying to fix this exception: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM

My project is maven based and I declared both dependencies (SWT 32 bit and SWT 64 bit) in the pom.xml file.

I am trying to dynamically load the correct JAR based on the Java architecture data model (sun.arch.data.model property) using the following function:

```
private static synchronized void loadLibrary(File jar) {
    try {
        URLClassLoader loader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        URL url = jar.toURI().toURL();

        for (URL it : Arrays.asList(loader.getURLs())) {
            if (it.equals(url)) {
                return;
            }
        }

        Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(loader, new Object[]{url});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to specify the path to the JAR. I see the JAR is downloaded in the .m2 folder but I guess that I can't specify that path. My guess is that I should specify the path to the Java cache were JNLP will download the JARs. Am I correct?

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing this: I have downloaded the 32 and 64 bit jars and put them in the resource folder of my project (/swt/swt_x86.jar and /swt/swt_x86_64.jar). Then, in the places where I needed the jar I used the function mentioned in the subject to load it based on the Java architecture.

Answer (score 2):

I would create separate 32-bit and 64-bit versions of your artifact. This can be achieved by wrapping the swt dependencies into profiles (you could call them `32bit` and `64bit`) and then activate the suitable profile. You can then produce two artifacts of different name or version (or classifier).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. I am actually looking for a faster and simpler method to do this. The context is that I am using JWebBrowser to show some Youtube videos in my application and that is the only spot in the app where there is difference between architecture and I thought that by loading the appropriate JAR I could solve this fast and deploy it to the users. I know that this is a hack but I want to do it fast.
P.S. Good answer, thank you.